# Adding multiple Reducer using ChainReducer throwing Exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have already read previous posts related to this but didn't get anything meaningful.

My use case is :

1. Aggregate Impression and click data
2. Separate Clicked and non-clicked data in different files.

I have written mapper and reducer for that but that reducer's output is data containing clicked & non-clicked and it is going in same file. I want to separate that data so clicked data should be present in one file and non clicked should be present in other file.

**Error :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reducer has been already set
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.Chain.checkReducerAlreadySet(Chain.java:662)
```

**Code**

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true");
    conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
    conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec");
    conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type", "BLOCK");
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "IMPRESSION_CLICK_COMBINE_JOB");
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setReducerClass(ImpressionClickReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);

    // FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    // job.setMapperClass(ImpressionMapper.class);

    Path p = new Path(args[2]);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    fs.exists(p);
    fs.delete(p, true);

    /**
     * Here directory of impressions will be present
     */
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, ImpressionMapper.class);
    /**
     * Here directory of clicks will be present
     */
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, ClickMapper.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

    job.setNumReduceTasks(10);

    job.setPartitionerClass(TrackerPartitioner.class);

    ChainReducer.setReducer(job, ImpressionClickReducer.class,  Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, new Configuration(false));

    ChainReducer.addMapper(job, ImpressionClickMapper.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, new Configuration(false));

    //Below mentioned line is giving Error
    //ChainReducer.setReducer(job, ImpressionAndClickReducer.class,  Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, new Configuration(false));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

ChainReducer is used to chain Map tasks after the Reducer, you can only call `setReducer()` once ([See the code here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/chain/Chain.java#L650)).

From the [Javadocs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/chain/ChainReducer.html):

> The ChainReducer class allows to chain multiple Mapper classes after a
>   Reducer within the Reducer task.
>
> Using the ChainMapper and the ChainReducer classes is possible to compose Map/Reduce jobs that look like [MAP+ / REDUCE MAP*]. And immediate benefit of this pattern is a dramatic reduction in disk IO.

So the idea is you set a single Reducer and then chain Map operations after that.

It sounds like you actually want to use [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). The Hadoop Javadocs provide an example on how to use it. With this you can define more than one output and its down to you which output key/values get written to.